# Who is Jesse Perring?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is he Lee Sin's brother or something? I read it in his ultimate description about whoever taught it too him, and heard him again in the super old Ezreal champion spotlight.

Comment: Don't spam tags, this is not youtube...

Comment: Questions asking about casters / employees in the gaming industry is off-topic on our site. please read the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: This question is actually related to game lore and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

haha, jesse perring is a Riot employee who was once one of the best LoL players around. He is still very very good, and thus the legacy of Jesse Perring lives on. So consider him the Chuck Norris of League of Legends.